# Why can't I declare an empty constructor in a c++ class that extends from one with a private constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

I am trying to understand usage of private constructors with inheritance (I am fairly new to C++) and in testing things have run into the following:

```
vestigial.cc: In constructor ‘ExtraSample::ExtraSample()’:
vestigial.cc:34:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘Sample::Sample()’
  ExtraSample() {};
```

using this to compile: g++ -std=c++11 vestigial.cc

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Sample {
public:
    ~Sample(){
        cout << name << " died " << endl;
    };
    void what() {
        cout << name << " hat" << endl;
    }
private:
    Sample(const string n) {
        name = n;
    };
    friend class SampleOwner;
    string name;
};


class SampleOwner {
public:
    static Sample* createSample(const string n) {
        return new Sample(n);
    }
};

class ExtraSample : Sample {
public:
private:
    ExtraSample() {};
};
```

In summary - why is this code invalid?

Thank you!

Comment: One of the if not the only way to prevent inheritance is to make your constructor private

Comment: There is no default ctor in your base class so the compiler has no idea which one to call. In this case you need to call the base class's constructor implicitly but since it's private you can't.

Comment: Adding a public constructor does allow me to compile, but that seems to defeat the purpose of having the private constructor, which makes sense from the first comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a derived class is initialized, the base class has to be initialized first. You can specify which base class constructor to call by mentioning the base class's name in a ctor-initializer in the derived class constructor. If you do not explicitly specify this, then the compiler attempts to call the base class's default constructor.

However, this base class has no default constructor, hence the error message. Note that you wouldn't be able to call `Sample::Sample(string)` anyway, since it's private, so effectively it's impossible to derive from `Sample` at all.

If you want the base class's constructor to be callable only by the derived class, make it `protected` instead!

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the code invalid?

The caller can not access the private constructor.

---

There are several ways to make it possible to call a private base class constructor.

- modify base class to name the derived class as a friend
- add a named constructor to the base class as either protected or public, and it can call the derived constructor.  (the named constructor idiom methods are static)
- modify the base class to name the function as a friend.
- modify the private constructor to be protected